# Webservice Rest com PHP

Tags: php, web-service, rest, framework

Estou fazendo uma pesquisa que resultará o desenvolvimento de um aplicativo e chegamos a questão de utilizar webservices, tenho algumas questões que gostaria da ajuda de vocês.

1. Vamos utilizar Rest, quais frameworks PHP trabalham com esse tipo de webservice?
2. Seria "difícil" implementar um webservice sem framework? O que eles tem a oferecer?
3. Me passem links para estudo quem falem dos frameworks mais utilizados para esse procedimento.

Comment: 1. Slim, Zend, Laravel, apenas perguntei por mais frameworks.
2. Me da essa resposta ai sabidão, pergunta la no google.
3. Perguntei pra quem já trabalhou assim e pode ajudar passando links para que eu possa estudar, não quero tudo na boca feito buceta não filhão. Não quer responder, fica caladinho!

Comment: Sem contar que o link que você passou é de 2006, bom esforço de procura o seu, e como foi citado na introdução da pergunta, o padrão sera REST.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1 - Silex, Slim, Lumem ... e até frameworks mais robustos como Symfony, Zend e Laravel podem ser utilizados.

2 - É muito mais viável utilizar um framework para criação de webservices do que utilizar a metodologia "faça você mesmo", por alguns motivos:

- O framework possui muitas funcionalidades prontas.
- O framework está sendo desenvolvido e melhorado a um bom tempo e existem muitas pessoas envolvidas, tanto na parte de testes quanto na implementação de novas funcionalidades.
- Outro motivo é que seu framework feito em uma semana não vai garantir a integridade da app, pois não houve tempo para cobrir todos os casos teste que um framework popular vai atingir(sempre vai ter algo para corrigir "aqui ou alí").
- Você vai demorar mais tempo para produzir seu próprio framework, tempo esse que poderia ser gasto em funcionalidades da app.

3 - A maneira mais correta de entender como funcionam é ler a documentação oficial, pois possuem as práticas corretas e recomendas pelos criadores dos projetos para melhor utilização, bons estudos.

- www.gajotres.net/best-available-php-restful-micro-frameworks/
- laravel.com/docs/5.1/controllers#restful-resource-controllers
- lumen.laravel.com/
- silex.sensiolabs.org/
- www.slimframework.com/